# Can't find nuts for old mavic wheel

Tags: wheels, rear-wheel

I picked up an old mavic wheel, and I'm having a tough time just finding some nuts for the axles. I went through a bin at my community bike shop and couldnt find anything that fit the threads.
The wheel says CXP 22 on it.

Is there a specific kind of nut I should be looking for for these wheels?

Comment: CXP 22 is a rim that can be built with any kind of hub. To answer, we need to know which hub you have.

Comment: Says 'Formula' on the hub

Comment: Turns out i needed race style nuts. The kind of nuts that have a flared end thats independent of the rest of the nut

Comment: @kingkelly you may write your own answer. It will help the next one with a similar problem. Best would be to provide more information about the hub in your question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i needed race style nuts. The kind of nuts that have a flared end thats independent of the rest of the nut.

[image: Track Nuts]

Answer (score 0):

You could always try taking the wheel to a fixing and fasteners specialist they would be able to measure  and potentially match the thread and then supply you with the correct fittings. If that drew a blank and the thread turned out to be a extremely rare type and not obtainable then a set of QR axles and skewers are cheaply available online in different standard sizes and you could just swap out the axles for something more readily available without having to change your wheelset or hubs.